# What does the phrase 'put up' means?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

In the following sentence, what does the phrase *put up* mean?

*I watched her **put up** peaches and tomatoes, placing jar after jar of jewel-colored fruits and vegetables on the basement shelves.*

Comment: It means "can":  *to put in a can : preserve by sealing in airtight cans or jars.*

Comment: @HotLicks Is it not just "put them on the shelf" in this context? I've never heard _put up_ being used in the sense of preserving.

Comment: @OliverMason - The idiom "put X on the shelf", in the US, means to store something away with the understanding that it will likely never be used again.  If you put your old computer "on the shelf" you probably don't expect to ever take it off again (at least until they move you into the old folks home).

Answer (score 2):

Comment from Hot Licks

> It means "can": to put in a can : preserve by sealing in airtight cans or jars.

As a native English speaker, I would have never known that - even with the (limited) context of the quotation. I assumed it just meant, literally, **putting** them **up**, on the shelves.

This seems to be US (southern US?) slang; for example: [Preserve The Season and "Put Up" Some Peaches](https://www.southernliving.com/fruits/peach/canning-peaches)

As the phrase is in quotation marks in that article, I assume it is not very common or is acknowledged as informal.

Comment: Prior to the advent of freezers, the only ways to preserve foodstuffs were to can them or dry them.  The metaphor referenced by "putting up" is the act of placing a "can" (what's now referred to as a "canning jar") on a shelf.

Comment: Not restricted to the South: https://bklynlocavore.com/2013/07/11/bourbon-sour-cherries/

Comment: Of course this is only one interpretation—and the least common. More commonly, *put up* would mean to literally put them up on the shelves . . . (It makes no sense to ask somebody, "Can you put these up for me?" in a canning sense when discussing any number of other objects.)

Comment: @JasonBassford - Actually, the most common use of "put up" in the US is likely in sentences such as "I simply can't *put up* with that idiot brother-in-law of mine any more."

Comment: @HotLicks but that makes no sense in the context, while both the literal and the canning interpretations do.

Comment: @JamesRandom - Such is idiomatic speech.

Comment: @HotLicks hence the idiom "put up or shut up" ;-)